# Insert space between row items in a list CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

In a list, I am trying to insert space of around 10px after 4 / 8 items in a list. I tried adding - `.box:nth-child(4n + 1) { padding-top: 10px; }` but then it is also adding padding to 1st item(which makes sense in `n = 0`).  Let me know a cleaner way of creating the same effect, as this list is dynamic and items in a list may varies from 1 / 2 / 3 / 4/ 5 / 6/ 7/ 8/ 9.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  padding: 10px;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-item {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box {
  width: 25%;
}

// .box:nth-child(4n + 1) { padding-top: 10px; }
.header {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 1</div>
        <div class="content">Content 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 2</div>
        <div class="content">Content 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 3</div>
        <div class="content">Content 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 4</div>
        <div class="content">Content 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 5</div>
        <div class="content">Content 5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 6</div>
        <div class="content">Content 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 7</div>
        <div class="content">Content 7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 8</div>
        <div class="content">Content 8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="header">Header 9</div>
        <div class="content">Content 9</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.box:nth-child(4n + 5) ` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh yeah ..thx but the problem is its not going to add that css to 6 7 8 ...only 5 / 9 and so on :)

Comment: `.box:nth-child(4) ~ .box` ??  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGVZYpx Looks like you try to avoid the first row ?